# unable to drag and drop a single file in react without using any library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to add drag and drop functionality for uploading excel file in react without trying any other react library, but not sure where i'm doing wrong. I've tried as below code but still its not working.

Here is my code:

```
export function App() {
  const fileRef = React.useRef(null);

  const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files[0]) {
      onDrop(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  };
  const onDrop = (file) => {
    console.log(file);
  };

  const onButtonClick = () => {
    fileRef.current.click();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="file"
        className="inputFile"
        name="file"
        onDrop={onChangeHandler}
        ref={fileRef}
        id="input-file-upload"
      />
      <label
        htmlFor="input-file-upload"
        id="label-file-upload"
        onDrop={(e) => onDrop(e.dataTransfer.files[0])}
      >
        <div>
          <button
            style={{ display: "block", margin: "auto" }}
            onClick={onButtonClick}
          >
            Add File
          </button>
          Drag and drop files
        </div>
      </label>
     <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the link to the code: [code-base](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-albattani-8hglm9?file=/src/index.js:85-1125)

Could anyone help me in getting drag and drop functionality for excel file upload?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

export function App() {
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);

  const handleDragEnter = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsDragging(true);
  };

  const handleDragLeave = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsDragging(false);
  };

  const handleDragOver = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  const handleDrop = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsDragging(false);

    const file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
    setSelectedFile(file);
    console.log(file);
  };

  const handleFileInputChange = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    setSelectedFile(file);
    console.log(file);
  };

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    document.getElementById("input-file-upload").click();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div
        className={`dropzone ${isDragging ? "dragging" : ""}`}
        onDragEnter={handleDragEnter}
        onDragLeave={handleDragLeave}
        onDragOver={handleDragOver}
        onDrop={handleDrop}
      >
        <input
          type="file"
          id="input-file-upload"
          className="inputFile"
          onChange={handleFileInputChange}
        />
        <label htmlFor="input-file-upload" id="label-file-upload">
          <div>
            <button
              style={{ display: "block", margin: "auto" }}
              onClick={handleButtonClick}
            >
              Add File
            </button>
            {selectedFile ? (
              <p>Selected File: {selectedFile.name}</p>
            ) : (
              <p>Drag and drop files</p>
            )}
          </div>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I used your sandbox, and I was able to drag my file over there. I am using `isDragging` state variable to track the drag state. The handleDragEnter, handleDragLeave, handleDragOver, and handleDrop event handlers are used to handle the drag and drop events.

Comment: Hi, Could you please help me in this css one which you've mentioned in the answer - **className={`dropzone ${isDragging ? "dragging" : ""}`}**